# How to implement a basic "sponge function"?

Tags: hash, implementation, sponge

In Chapter 6 of *Serious Cryptography*, they write about the **sponge function**:

> 1. It XORs the first message block, M1, to H0, a predefined initial value of the internal state (for example, the all-zero string). Message blocks are all the same size and smaller than the internal state.
> 2. A permutation, P, transforms the internal state to another value of the same size.
> 3. It XORs block M2 and applies P again, and then repeats this for the message blocks M3, M4, and so on. This is called the **absorbing phase**.
> 4. After injecting all the message blocks, it applies P again and extracts a block of bits from the state to form the hash. (If you need a longer hash, apply P again and extract a block.) This is called the **squeezing phase**.
>
> The security of a sponge function depends on the length of its internal state and the length of the blocks. If message blocks are r-bit long and the internal state is w-bit long, then there are c = w – r bits of the internal state that can’t be modified by message blocks. The value of c is called a sponge’s capacity, and the security level guaranteed by the sponge function is c/2. For example, to reach 256-bit security with 64-bit message blocks, the internal state should be w = 2 × 256 + 64 = 576 bits. Of course, the security level also depends on the length, n, of the hash value. The complexity of a collision attack is therefore the smallest value between 2^{n/2} and 2^{c/2}, while the complexity of a second preimage attack is the smallest value between 2^n and 2^{c/2}.
>
> To be secure, the permutation P should behave like a random
> permutation, without statistical bias and without a mathematical structure
> that would allow an attacker to predict outputs. As in compression
> function–based hashes, sponge functions also pad messages, but the
> padding is simpler because it doesn’t need to include the message’s
> length. The last message bit is simply followed by a 1 bit and as many
> zeroes as necessary.

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sponge_function) is too opaque for turning into code as well.

Wondering if one could show a simplistic demonstration of a realish-world sponge function, to sail home these 4 bullet points on how it works.

Some [questions](https://keccak.team/sponge_duplex.html) related to implementing it:

- What is the block size? Assuming 512
- What is the input data (utf-8, etc.)? Does it matter?
- What to XOR the first message block with? What number? And future blocks too?

I don't really know where to begin, haven't found any code snippets related to "sponge functions" either.

The [Keccak Sponge Functions paper](https://keccak.team/files/SpongeFunctions.pdf) is a bit too math heavy to be able to glean a clear software implementation from it (for me at least).

Just looking for the bare basics. Perhaps [this](https://www.oryx-embedded.com/doc/keccak_8c_source.html) is as simple as it can get?

Comment: I've made the question less JavaScript specific, as that would be off topic here; the questions you have about the implementation should be on topic. Note that providing sample code still isn't considered on topic here.

Comment: Ok I've removed the snippet, thanks. I found the [keccak sponge function in readable form](https://github.com/lancejpollard/hash/blob/make/lib/keccak-sponge.c), but it's quite dense and involved, can a sponge function not just be very simple to demonstrate how it works?

Comment: Uh, sure. Maybe there are simple implementations available (there are simplified AES specs used for learning purposes, for instance), but I don't know any. Not sure if other sponge functions would be more applicable. Spritz is certainly deliberately simple, so maybe have a look at that *for learning purposes*. Not sure if the sponge functionality is separated out of the stream cipher in their implementation though. SPONGENT also looks pretty simple. I also saw a paper where a hash was used as underlying function. Now that's of course a bit strange, but it might be helpful for learning purposes

Comment: You forgot some important part of this 1. Every team must submit code for the SHA-3 competition, 2. SHA-3 standard is given by the [NIST](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.202.pdf) and they have test vectors, too. I might call this dupe of this [Step-by-step working out with example input for NIST Hash Functions like SHA-1,SHA-2, and SHA-3](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/95783/18298)

Comment: I kind of assumed that the Keccak reference implementation would not be sufficiently "simple" and known, but sure you can use the functions of the ref implementation or a language specific port - if that's the answer then sure....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the sponge construction in simple terms?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/83258/what-is-the-sponge-construction-in-simple-terms)

Comment: No, I am looking for a technical implementation, ideally in code or pseudocode of some sort.